# Different tone of lens in glasses for bicycle

Tags: glasses

I bought yellow glasses for bicycle, and one lens has little bit less tone (more lighter). Is this defect?

Comment: For the record, I disagree with closing this question. I think that this is a good question, and I don't think that it's any more subjective than most of the questions on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably just means that the quality standards aren't too exacting. Kind of like how display panels with a few dead pixels aren't considered defective.

You could contact the manufacturer to ask whether the problem is covered by warranty, or you could just return them and buy a different brand. There's no point in keeping glasses you dislike.